# NodeJS SQL Server data pull isn't waiting for promise completion

Tags: node.js, sql-server, es6-promise

I am rewriting an ASPX application using Node.  Part of this application is pulling data from a table in SQL Server.  I am doing this using async functions to try and force the data to be pulled prior to continuing on.  It is essential that I have the data before the next step.  However, when it returns from the await the response is null.

```
const getUserGroups = async (user) => {
    let qry = `Select role from [xxxxx] where LOWER(yyyyy)='${user.toLowerCase()}'`;
    let groups = await dataQuery.Select(qry, dbList.MCAIntranet)
    console.log("Groups: ", groups); //This is undefined
    return groups;
    // })
}
```

Here is the Select function:

```
const Select = async (query, database) => {
    // console.log(config[database]
    sql.connect(config[database], (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        let request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(query, (err, recordset) => {
            console.log(recordset)//displays correct data
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return null
            }
            return recordset;
        })
    });
}
```

I am using the mssql module, but since I am fairly new to Node I am uncertain where my mistake lies.

Thanks in advance for looking at this.

Comment: No idea, but your query is **wide open to injection attacks and syntax errors**, use parameterized queries

Comment: That isn't necessary in this instance.  No client data is being used.  Plus the query here is a start.  I can refactor after it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you current code, you don't return anything from your `Select` function. Espectially you are not wrapping your sql code in promise.

You say, you are using the `mssql` package. This already supports [async/await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait), so you should use the apropriate async calls instead of callbacks.

```
const Select = async (query, database) => {
   try {
     await sql.connect(config[database]);
     let request =  new sql.Request();
     let recordset = await request.query(query);
     return recordset;
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     return null;
   }
}
```

Furthermore you should read about parameterized queries, because currently your code is quite unsafe, ie it is vulnerable to SQL injections and invalid syntax errors.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.  As for the queries, like I mentioned above those will get resolved once I am ready to refactor.  This was just a quick and easy select query to get things working.  I will parameterize once I have a functional prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap your implementation with a Promise object, or `return Promise.resolve(data);`, and `return Promise.reject(err)`:

```
const Select = async (query, database) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // console.log(config[database]
    sql.connect(config[database], (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        let request = new sql.Request();
        
        request.query(query, (err, recordset) => {
            console.log(recordset)//displays correct data
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(recordset);
        })
    });
  });
}
```